# MathJax defining macro as final or last

Tags: javascript, latex, mathjax, tex

My task is to convert `\overline` symbol to `\overleftrightarrow` and `\oversegment` to `\overline`. The problem is that this is what I get on input (which is fundamentally wrong I know) but I can't modify it.

So based on this source: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros

I defined my macros:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
        Macros: {
            overline: ["{\\overleftrightarrow{#1}}", 1],
            oversegment: ["{\\overline{#1}}", 1]
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I have the input with `\oversegment`, it gets converted by second macro to `\overline`, and then it gets converted again by first macro to `\overleftrightarrow`, which is wrong. I want it converted only once and make it final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an easy way given the way macros are processed. The best way seems to be to replicate the [original function in the TeX input jax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/1c54436ae6166a91495aba8a98cc18816b4789df/unpacked/jax/input/TeX/jax.js#L786), i.e., add this function to your inline configuration block.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready", function () {
  var MML = MathJax.ElementJax.mml;
    MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.Add({
       macros: {
          oversegment: ['UnderOver','00AF']
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: After I found out that it's rather impossible with macros in a way I tried, I think your answer is best in the given circumstances - thanks!